# how to properly set environment of R in xp?

Tags: r

When I install R on  `G:\R-3.0.2`, I set path environment of R as `G:\R-3.0.2\bin\i386`.
it can work in xp CMD.

When I install R on  `C:\Program Files\R-3.0.2` , I set path environment of R as `C:\Program Files\R-3.0.2\bin\i386`, it does not work .

How to set path environment on `C:\Program Files\R-3.0.2` properly? Here is my full path statement when i have not added the folder of R.exe in the path value :

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;
```

Comment: There are two options, you can set PATH for user or system-wide. Can you show us the full PATH statement you're using?

Comment: What is the full path when you *have* set the path to R in the PATH variable. And I am going on a limb here: give us a screenshot...

Comment: If you just accepted the installation defaults, the path will be `C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.2\bin\i386`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path for the environment variable looks correct (you can double check by opening R and typing `R.home("bin")`).

If you've manually set an environment variable Win XP usually needs a reboot before other software recognises its existence.

Comment: when i reboot ,everything is ok .